# ':norm dtxdty' works different than '0dtxdty', what's happening?

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

On line `ay`, `0dtxdty` deletes the `a` (as I would expect), but `:norm dtxdty` does nothing, `norm!` and `exec` don't change it.

I wanted to use it as part of a command to align as explained [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_text_alignment), but to two different characters.

What am I doing wrong and what command will work just like normal mode `0dtxdty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
:normal 0dtxdty
```

stops processing after an error. In your case `dtx` results in an error, as there is no `x` on that line.

To ignore this error, use

```
silent! normal 0dtxdty
```

But be careful with `silent!`, you might hide errors, that you want to see.

Comment: Thank you. Not very important I guess but you included ```0``` at the beginning of normal which afaik does nothing since normal starts from column 0 anyway. I thought that errors in vim are displayed on the bottom of the screen, which is not the case for ```dtx``` nor ```tx```, even ```:h errors``` redirects to info about error messages. How can I know about errors in vim if they raise no message/can I somehow make it always display?

Comment: @Q.Q I don't know how to detect this error in a script. I think this is worth another question. Something like "How to detect errors in `:normal ...`?" with your example.